# "When the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, machine.config

So I get this error when publishing my ASP.NET MVC application. It works fine locally:

> " This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this
>   section using `<location allowOverride="false">` from an inherited
>   configuration file.

I had this error before that I fixed:

> "System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed."

I used the following code in my Web.config file:

```
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

So does anyone know how I can change my: `"<location allowOverride="false">` to true? Cause that must be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In IIS Manager, select the server node and in the bottom section `Feature Delegation`. Find your feature and change it to `Read/Write`.

You have to be an administrator to change this setting.

Comment: Ok I know this sounds very strange, but I dont have any IIS Manager on my PC. Iv'e tried all this steps but does not work: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785858%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Ok nevermind, I installed it. Where is the server node exactly?

Comment: @Cleon - In the tree on the left-hand side, it has your computer's name.

Comment: Ok so Im in Feature Delegation. Which feature should I change to Read/Write?

Comment: Should I just change them all to Read/Write?

Comment: No, you should have them the same way your production server is set up. This section allows certain settings to be overwritten in local web.config, Read/Write gives more power to anybody who can edit the web.config. It all depends on your environment, but keep in mind that maybe on a production server you wont have access to these settings.

Comment: @Cleon change the .NET Trust Levels Delegation to Read/Write and it should work

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error...so I solved with two steps.
First, adding code in web.config file.

```
<location path="yourdomain.com" allowOverride="true">
  <system.web>
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

and second, changing IIS Manger. 
select the server. 
Open Feature Delegation under management
change .NET Trust Level to Read/Write (from right hand Action panel)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was that I forgot that I had modified the "generic" web.config (the one that is located in **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework{Your .NET Framework}\Config\web.config**).

I had added `<location allowOverride="false">`, so I removed this tag and it worked as usual.