# Server Error in '/' Application Configuration Error

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, web-config

As per the image the error i have checked in web.config file and the changes i have made in it problem still persist.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <trust level="Full" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="APPXAUTH1" loginUrl="~/Home/UserLogin" protection="All" timeout="990"/>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
  <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

```
<location allowOverride="true">
</location>
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

as above i have used this in my web.config file even if i remove this **location allowOverride="true"** or this code **httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"** issue will still be same.Project i have used is MVC 4.5.1

website error is 
[image: website error]

Comment: check machine.config if something i blocking you. for more reference please check http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2007/04/11/111370.aspx

Comment: There are some results in google related to this problem. Did you try it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374806/when-the-site-administrator-has-locked-access-to-this-section-using-location-a https://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/tag/this-happens-when-the-site-administrator-has-locked-access-to-this-section-using-location-allowoverridefalse-from-an-inherited-configuration-file/

Comment: is problem solved?

Comment: Not yet just asking my hosting provider he told me to change trust level="Full"  to Medium but same issue persist he told me that they have changed the policy from Full to Medium